# How to know when a method finish in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

I have a problem with this method, i want to return a PDF file and when the method it's over i want to delete de file from the directory.

```
public ActionResult DescargaPdfCompara(string id)
    {
        var rutaPdf = string.Empty;
        var type = "application/pdf";

        try
        {

            DateTime ahora = DateTime.Now;
            var numeroAleatorio = new Random();
            int numeroRandomico = numeroAleatorio.Next(100000000, 1000000000);
            string Ruta = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"Reportes\" + Convert.ToString(ahora.Year + ahora.Month + ahora.Day + ahora.Hour + ahora.Minute + ahora.Second + numeroRandomico) + ".pdf");

            var result = SimuModel.ObtenerSabanaReporteComparativo(id);
            var resumen = SimuModel.ObtenerPreExcel(result);
            SimuModel.GenerarPdfCompa(result, resumen, Ruta);

            rutaPdf = Ruta;

            return File(rutaPdf, type);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(rutaPdf);
        }
    }
```

In the finally i delete the file but i got an error because the method can't find the file, for some reason the method delete the file before return it.

PD: Sorry for my english, i'm from Chile.

Thanks fro your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes` to read all the file contents to memory, then delete the file and return the contents with another overload of Controller.File method:

```
    public ActionResult GetFile()
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, "Hola, Chile!");
        var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
        System.IO.File.Delete(fileName);
        return File(bytes, "text/plain", "file.txt");
    }
```

Comment: @Maurinostroza podría hacer clic en "aceptar respuesta"

Answer (score 0):

Change return type ContentResult

remove finally section.

```
public ContentResult DescargaPdfCompara(string id)
{
    var rutaPdf = string.Empty;
    var type = "application/pdf";

    try
    {

        DateTime ahora = DateTime.Now;
        var numeroAleatorio = new Random();
        int numeroRandomico = numeroAleatorio.Next(100000000, 1000000000);
        string Ruta = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"Reportes\" + Convert.ToString(ahora.Year + ahora.Month + ahora.Day + ahora.Hour + ahora.Minute + ahora.Second + numeroRandomico) + ".pdf");

        var result = SimuModel.ObtenerSabanaReporteComparativo(id);
        var resumen = SimuModel.ObtenerPreExcel(result);
        SimuModel.GenerarPdfCompa(result, resumen, Ruta);

        rutaPdf = Ruta;

        return Content(rutaPdf, type);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        throw e;
    }

}
```

Comment: The file returns fine when i delete the finally section, the problem is that i have to delete it, thanks for your answer!